# How to use NPM config variables cross platform (win/linux)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

When using `npm_package_config_<variable>` usage is different per OS.

**package.json (Linux & Windows)**

```
config: {
    foo: "bar"
}
```

Then for usage:

**Linux**

```
node app.js --arg=$npm_package_config_foo
```

**Windows**

```
node app.js --arg=%npm_package_config_foo%
```

Thus I create 2 seperate `scripts` in my `package.json` but this feels cumbersome.

Any way to get this cross-platform?

*P.S. I'm aware of the [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) plugin, but this does not work for the above case, only for NODE_ENV.*

**UPDATE**

To avoid misinterpretation of the context, here is a real case scenario I'm looking for, to use this for Docker commands to specify port numbers:

**package.json**

```
"config": {
    "port": "3000"
}
...
"scripts": {
    "docker:build": "docker build --build-arg PORT=$npm_package_config_port -t my-app .",
    "docker:build:win": "docker build --build-arg PORT=%npm_package_config_port% -t my-app .",
}
```

Comment: If you're the author of `app.js` and the argument is always required then consider accessing `config.foo`, (in `package.json`), from within `app.js` itself. For example `var baz  = process.env.npm_package_config_foo`. Then your npm script in `package.json` would simply be `"scriptname": "node app.js"` Or is `app.js` third party?

Comment: Actually, I'm trying the use a config of `port` and use that in a Docker command. So `config: { "port": "3000" }` and then like `docker build --build-arg PORT=$npm_package_config_port -t myapp .`. Then, there is no Node.js runtime to process environment variables.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should use [`cross-var`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-var).

Then you can simplify to:

`"scripts": {
    "docker:build": "cross-var docker build --build-arg PORT=$npm_package_config_port -t my-app .",
}`

Comment: This actually solves my problem the easiest and most convenient way. Thanks!

Comment: My concerns is in relation with the number of packages introduced by `cross-var`. 

134 actually, so many dependencies for simple functionality
[dependency chart](http://npm.anvaka.com/#/view/2d/cross-var)

Comment: Maybe `cross-var-no-babel` with [10 dependencies](http://npm.anvaka.com/#/view/2d/cross-var-no-babel) rather than `cross-var` with 134

Answer (score 2):

This really doesn't require anything cross platform because you are not using Environment Variables. So really, you're just trying to read the `process.argv` that get passed in and determine which config variables need to be used from your `package.json`. You could use a package like [`yargs`](https://npmjs.com/package/yargs) which will read and parse your `process.argv` for you or you could parse the `process.argv` yourself and act accordingly.

Here is an example using yargs for the example given in the question, this logic would go inside `my-app.js`

```
const argv = require('yargs').argv;
const pkgJson = require('./package.json');

let config;

if (argv.arg) {
    let argSplit = argv.arg.split('_');
    let configVariable = argSplit[argSplit.length - 1];

    config = pkgJson.config[configVariable]
}
```

If you are in the need of using environment variables though, [`cross-env`](https://npmjs.com/package/cross-env) is the way to go you can do things like `cross-env PORT=3000 node server` to pass in a port etc, unlike what you have said in your question, `cross-env` is NOT limited to just `NODE_ENV`

#### Edit for Question update

Consolidate your NPM scripts for `docker:build` and `docker:build:win` into one script by doing

`docker build --build-arg PORT=$(node -p process.env.npm_package_config_port) -t my-app .`

The above will extract the value that NPM sets to the environment variables based on your config and then return it. I don't use docker so I haven't tested with Docker but I did test with `echo` and the value was returned from `$(node -p process.env.npm_package_config_port)`.

#### Update 2

Looks like even though the above commands would work in Powershell when on windows, NPM will ignore the environment that the command is run in (GitBash, Cygwin, Powershell, etc.) and spawn its own shell and run the command using `cmd.exe`. In short, you will need either two distinctly different build commands or you will need some other intermediary build process.

For more info see [this issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6543) from the NPM repo on GitHub.

Comment: @Nicky I updated my answer, see if the updated helps.

Comment: fwiw - I also don't use docker. When I did a test with echo on Mac OSX it correctly printed `PORT=3000`, however, It failed for me on Win Vista via _Command Prompt_. The following was printed instead `PORT=$(node -p process.env.npm_package_config_port)`.

Comment: @RobC This is because the sub-expression syntax `$()` is supported in Powershell but not cmd.exe

Comment: @peteb Thanks, that's useful to know. Is Powershell Windows 10 only?

Comment: @RobC nope, its under Start --> Accessories --> Windows Powershell

Comment: @peteb - Thanks again. TIL Powershell is much better, however a test with `echo` also prints `PORT=$(node -p process.env.npm_package_config_port)` as per Command Prompt.

Comment: @RobC that's not how you execute the command. It would be `echo $(node -p process.env.npm_package_config_port)`. See my above edit about running this directly from NPM. There are limitations due to under-the-hood shell swapping.

Comment: Indeed, and after running `npm run docker:build` that prints `$(node -p process.env.npm_package_config_port)` - Regardless of whether the `PORT=` is there or not the port number `3000` is certainly never printed whether via  _Command Prompt_ or _Powershell_

Answer (score 1):

**short answer:** Not possible to achieve cross platform solely within `package.json` without separating into two scripts as you have.

**long answer:** If a single script is paramount over *'cumbersome'* then utilize a custom node script and `exec()` the command from there.

**package.json**

```json
"config": {
  "port": "3000",
  "name": "my-app"
},
"scripts": {
    "docker:build": "node .scripts/docker.js"
}
```

**docker.js**

```js
'use strict';

var exec = require('child_process').exec,
    port = process.env.npm_package_config_port || 3000,
    name = process.env.npm_package_config_name || 'my-app',
    cmd = 'docker build --build-arg PORT=' + port + ' -t ' + name + ' .';

exec(cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    if (error) {
        console.error(error);
        process.exit(1);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you think creating no new dependencies is a worthy goal then [RobC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42169924/4376643) is great, but how about add a parameter option to "my-app"

```
node app.js --envarg=npm_package_config_foo
```

Then in your app

```
  ...
  switch(process.argv[i]){
      ...
      case "--envarg":
          // index check here
          foo = process.env[process.argv[++i]]
          break;
      ...
  }
```

or some such (the same way you were dealing with "---arg").
Dependencies can be great time savers, but they also introduce complexities which increase the chance of future headaches.