# Question about CLI и package.json nest.js

Tags: nestjs, command-line-interface, package.json

Question about CLI и package.json nest.js
Typeorm migration needs to pass filename via CLI package.json:

```
 "typeorm:generate-migration": "npm run typeorm -- -d ./typeorm-migration.config.ts migration:generate ./migrations/$npm_config_name",
```

Call:

```
 npm run typeorm:generate-migration --name=CreatePost
```

The name is not taken from the query string, but prints '$npm_config_name'.
$npm_config_name doesn't seem to work with npm 7. In Windows it works if you use %npm_config_name%
I searched for a long time and did not find a cross-platform version of a simple

Comment: this answer solved cross-platform problem using `cross-var` [https://stackoverflow.com/a/42262105/12923831](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42262105/12923831)

Answer (score 0):

one solution I had was to pass the cross-env-shell before running npm.
Example:

```
"typeform:generate-migration":
 "cross-env-shell npm run typeorm -- -d ./typeorm-migration.config.ts migration:generate ./migrations/$npm_config_name",
```

Comment: Please turn the question into an answer.